# Howto create a C# Application that blocks pc hibernation?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, windows-7

I want to make a program to wake me up, but if I leave it and go to sleep the pc ends up sleeping.
How can I force it to never sleep if this application is running?

I'm on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Set it from the Energy Panel, why make it in your application anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword you are looking for is "Power Management".

Try this article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163386.aspx

Or even better, another similar StackOverflow question:

[Prevent windows from going into sleep when my program is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629240/prevent-windows-from-going-into-sleep-when-my-program-is-running)