# How to track if the Windows 7 goes for sleep or hibernate programmatically in c++ as done in windows xp?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I have a callback

```
WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {}
```

that checks if the windows system goes to sleep/hibernation by using `WM_POWERBROADCAST` event. But the same is not working for windows 7.

So for Windows 7, how it can be done? Which events is to be used? What's the difference between windows xp and windows 7 in the way of handling power events.

Comment: One difference is that Windows Vista and later won't wait if you tell them to.  They'll just go right on suspending, regardless of what value you return to the OS when this event fires.

Comment: You'll have to define what you mean by "not working". That phrase carries next to no information. Be specific. I suspect that you are not trying to check or track, despite what you state. I suspect that you are trying to block.

Comment: I am using WM_POWERBROADCAST message handling to stop pc from going to hibernate or sleep. This works in windows xp. But the same does not works on windows 7 that means it goes to hibernate or sleep.

Comment: Thanks John, Then is there no way to detect when windows 7 is going to sleep or hibernate and avoid doing that

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you actually want to avoid going to sleep for some reason.  For that, please see the answers posted here: [Prevent windows from going into sleep when my program is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629240/prevent-windows-from-going-into-sleep-when-my-program-is-running)

Comment: Thank You. But Does SetThreadExecutionState works for windows 7 also?