# How to run a powershell script as a windows service?

Tags: powershell, nssm

I have below powershell script which fires refresh command every 1 min or so. It works perfectly fine when run manually from powershell. But I am having issues running it as a service.

```
while (1) {
  $wsh = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
  $wsh.SendKeys('+{F15}')
  Start-Sleep -seconds 59
}
```

I used [nssm](https://nssm.cc/) to convert it to a service and when I query it using `Get-Service` command, I see it as running. However, I no longer see it's effects (system goes to sleep after 1 min as opposed to staying up which happens when I run this manually on powershell.)

```
Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  ps-refresh         ps-refresh
```

Are there any extra steps required ?

Comment: It will run in the non-interactive session 0 that is reserved for services. There is no desktop it could send Shift+F15 _to_.

Comment: But that whole thing is a hack anyway. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629240/prevent-windows-from-going-into-sleep-when-my-program-is-running) how to do this properly. If you create a program like that, it should work as service too.