# How to prevent system from going to hibernate？

Tags: java, windows

I want to develop a Java application, hoping that the system never goes to hibernate when my application running.

The application will be deployed in Windows.

Is there any way to realize this?

Comment: Look at this post :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/629240/prevent-windows-from-going-into-sleep-when-my-program-is-running

Comment: What can java do in this?

Comment: While not specifically Java related. I do know of a guy who tied a mouse to an oscillating fan to get it to drag the mouse back and forwards. Not exactly high tech, but it works (and it is humorous).

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in java for this.

There are windows API to prevent hibernation. See this thread [Prevent windows from going into sleep when my program is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629240/prevent-windows-from-going-into-sleep-when-my-program-is-running)

You could all call them via JNI or [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to avoid your system going into Hibernate mode when your application is running:

1) I don't know which Windows operating system you are talking about; but we can disable or enable Hibernation at an operating system level. The enabling/disabling method might differ for different Window versions.

2) Another way would be to write a C++ program that uses Win32 API to interact at system level. After writing the code, you can export it as a DLL library and then use it in the Java program. Below link provides a sample code that will help you achieve similar functionality.

http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/system/messagehandling/article.php/c6907/JavaC-PC-Standby-Detect-and-Prevent.htm

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems when i wanted to connect via RDP to my pc, i left teamviewer on, but my pc went to hibernate/sleep and this is my solution how i keep my pc "active".

Try this, go to Control Panel->Power Options:

[image: This image shows how things look like on Windows 7]

and there u can select power plan, click on "Change plan settings" and u will get to this screen:

[image: This image shows how things look like on Windows 7, edit plan settings]

Hope that this will help u.

If u need some programmatic solution, try with this link:
[How do you keep the machine awake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52874/how-do-you-keep-the-machine-awake)