# How to prevent my screen from going black when my media player is playing a video in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

I am developing a video media player using Java (using NetBeans). I am having a problem to keep my screen on, while the video is playing. Each time I play a video using my video player, the computer screen goes black after 15 min, while I am watching the video. How to keep it awake?

Comment: Related (Java): [How do you keep the machine awake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52874/how-do-you-keep-the-machine-awake)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you keep the machine awake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52874/how-do-you-keep-the-machine-awake)

Answer (score 1):

Schedueling your mouse to move programatically can do the trick.

```
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                java.awt.Robot robot = new java.awt.Robot();
                robot.mouseMove(0, 0);
                robot.mouseMove(1, 1);
            } catch (AWTException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 900000); //move every 15 mins
```

Comment: Thanks let me try it: was using this code to move the mouse but did not know where exactly include it

Comment: Robot hal = new Robot();
         while(true){
             hal.delay(1000 * 30);       
            Point pObj = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
            System.out.println(pObj.toString() + "x>>" + pObj.x + "  y>>" + pObj.y);
            hal.mouseMove(pObj.x + 1, pObj.y + 1);  
            hal.mouseMove(pObj.x - 1, pObj.y - 1);
            pObj = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
            System.out.println(pObj.toString() + "x>>" + pObj.x + "  y>>" + pObj.y);
         }

Comment: Thanks Yamenk for your reply